# Handling Facebook access token in Facebook SDK 3.2

Tags: ios, facebook, access-token

How do i handle the `Facebook SDK 3.2` for iOS?. And also How do i use the Facebook Access Token in this?.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How to get the FB Access Token using fb iOS sdk v3.2:

```
[FBSession activeSession].accessTokenData.accessToken
```

Not sure what you're wanting to know in regard to handling the SDK, but here's more info on version 3.2:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorial/iossdk/upgrading-from-3.1-to-3.2/

Comment: Yeah, this is where I get it, but how can I save it?

Comment: in Facebook's iOS SDK 3.x, the saving of the token happens automatically. if you want to cache it yourself, look into FBSessionTokenCachingStrategy: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/3.2/class/FBSessionTokenCachingStrategy

Comment: Yeah, I did it and it worked great! I suggest it to everyone that have problems with the Access Token and wants to save it to use that -- it's awesome!